# Cortar un texto sin partir la palabra

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito cortar un texto por la mitad exactamente pero nunca debe darse la opción de que se parta una palabra, actualmente se me parte y no se realmente como hacerlo

```
// Obtengo el texto
let textoenriquecido = $('.risk-text').attr('data-text-test');

// Miro lo que mide y lo divido entre 2
let texto_final = textoenriquecido.length;
let divido = texto_final/2;

// Finalmente lo parto por la mitad
let primero = textoenriquecido.substring(0,divido);
let segundo = textoenriquecido.substring(divido);
```

Answer (score 3):

Tendrás que comprobar si el carácter por donde cortas es parte de una palabra o no. Si te guías solo por espacios, una solución sencilla sería añadir un while antes de dividir el texto, que recalcule `divido` hasta que no coincida con ningún espacio:

```js
while (textoenriquecido[divido] === ' ') {
    divido++;
}
```

Algunos puntos a tener en cuenta:

- El texto se dividirá por el centro, o más adelante, pero no más atrás (si quieres que se divida por el lugar más cercano al centro puedes pensar en cómo hacer el algoritmo para que lo encuentre, la respuesta de phpMyGuel lo hace).
- Así como lo tienes ahora `divido` podría ser contener decimales, y eso te dará error, así que te aconsejo que lo calcules así: `let divido = Math.floor(texto_final / 2);`

Answer (score 2):

Como bien te ha dicho el colega @ArianJM, necesitas encontrar un número no decimal para la mitad de tu frase y luego ir accediendo a los caracteres del `string` hasta encontrar uno que sea `" "`, considerándose este como un separador entre palabras.

Ya que te han puesto una manera de conseguirlo buscando en caracteres posteriores, te pongo yo una para hacerlo también en los anteriores, dando de esta manera con una mitad algo más exacta (ya que va a buscar el caracter `" "` más próximo tanto anterior como posteriormente).

Para hacerlo me apoyo en un bucle `while` y una *bandera* para especificar la condición de salida y uso una variable acumulativa para poder sumársela o restársela a la posición de caracter central dependiendo de si quiero buscar antes o después de este.

Por último la función devuelve un `array` con ambas mitades.

```js
let texto1 = "En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor";
let texto2 = "fdsdsfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsdsdfssdfdssdfsasa";

console.log('Texto 1:');
console.log(partir_texto(texto1));

console.log('Texto 2:');
console.log(partir_texto(texto2));

function partir_texto(texto) {
  let caracteres = texto.length;
  let mitad = Math.floor(caracteres/2);
  let contador = 0;
  let salir = false;
  let frase_partida = new Array();
  
  while (salir === false) {
    let anterior = mitad - contador;
    let posterior = mitad + contador;
    
    if (anterior < 0 && posterior > caracteres) {
      salir = true;
      return ('La frase no se puede partir sin que una de sus palabras quede cortada');
    }
  
    if (texto[anterior] === ' ') {
      mitad = anterior;
      salir = true;
    }
  
    if (texto[posterior] === ' ') {
      mitad = posterior;
      salir = true;
    }
    
    contador++;
  }
  
  frase_partida.push(texto.substring(0, mitad));
  frase_partida.push(texto.substring(mitad, caracteres));
  
  return frase_partida;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

Para evitar casos en los que se caía en un bucle infinito cuando la función no podía encontrar un espacio por donde partir la frase, se ha añadido una condición extra de salida. En dicho caso en vez de retornar el `array` con cada una de las mitades de la frase se devuelve un mensaje de error.

Comment: ¡Muy buena!, quizá tendrías que poner algún seguro para que `anterior` no sea nunca menor que 0, y `posterior` nunca sea mayor que `caracteres - 1`.

Comment: Tienes razón, edito mi respuesta para añadirlo.

Answer (score 2):

Te podría valer algo así, pongo un ejemplo con un texto que si fuera justo por la mitad partiría la palabra, pero de esta manera, con un split, obtenemos en un array todas las palabras, y así separamos el texto por la mitad de las palabras sin cortar ninguna:

```js
 let textoenriquecido = "aaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbb cccc dd";
 let textoCortado = cortarPalabra(textoenriquecido);
 console.log("TEXTO CORTADO 1: " + textoCortado[0]);
 console.log("TEXTO CORTADO 2: " + textoCortado[1]);
 
 function cortarPalabra(texto){
  
      let array = texto.split(" ");

      let array_length = array.length;
      let palabra_intermedia = array_length/2;

      let texto_cortado1 = "";
      let texto_cortado2 = "";

      for (let i=0; i<palabra_intermedia; i++) {
          texto_cortado1 += array[i] + " ";
      }
      
      for (let i=palabra_intermedia; i<array_length; i++) {
          texto_cortado2 += array[i] + " ";
      }

      let array_result = [texto_cortado1, texto_cortado2];
      
      return array_result;
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias crear una funcion que se encargue de esto.

Crear una funcion que tome como parametro un string.

Al string recibido aplicarle `string.split(" ")`, y el array devuelto guardarlo en una variable.

Luego queda calcular el largo del array, y con un for agregar todas esas palabras en una variable, y volver a realizar lo mismo con la otra mitad.

Y al final solo queda devolver un array que contenga dos elementos, que seran nuestros strings, uno con la primer mitad, y el otro con la segunda.

```
function cutTextInHalf(str) {
    
        str = str.split(" ");
        let strLength = str.length;
        let strLengthHalf = Math.ceil(strLength / 2);
        let firstHalf = '';
        let secondHalf = '';
    
        for ( let i = 0; i < strLengthHalf; i++ ) {
            firstHalf += ` ${ str[i] }`;
        }
    
        for ( let i = strLengthHalf; i < strLength; i++ ) {
            secondHalf += ` ${ str[i] } `;
        }
    
        return [ firstHalf.trim(), secondHalf.trim() ]
    }
```